# <BODY> position off, can't add fixed background image

Tags: css

The  tag position on this page is off: http://www.starcraft-source.com/

It's like it has a 40+ top margin on it

I can't figure out why and I'm trying to add a fixed background image and it's really not looking right.  Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: I am using FF and doesn't seems any problem to the page

Comment: @xandy: I finally see what he means. If you have Firebug, go to the body tag and twiddle the `background-position`, change `bottom` to `0px` and then see what happens with `-10px`, `10px`, etc.

Comment: Or if you're using Firebug, just hover over the body tag in the HTML tab - it'll show you that this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition that's causing it is this:

```
#hd {
    margin-top: 99px;
    position: relative;
}
```

If you turn that off, the apparent margin on the body goes away. Somehow, its being the first item in the page and being positioned relatively is causing it to go like that. I'm not certain of the precise reason why.

Comment: Everything I do with the CSS to create the same effect without the margin majorly messes up the page.... any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to be able to add a background image to this page... so I need to remove that relative position and maintain the same effect on the page where the image is positioned over the navigation bar.

Comment: Without knowing quite what you're trying to do it's impossible to say. Note how the `html` has the main gradient, and the `body` already has a background for the footer (and the bar at the top as a background too). You'll probably need to create another element or manipulate an existing one. What sort of image is it (i.e. what space will it take, does it go over the top of things, etc.)?